# How do I add a point on QML Maps by typing in coordinates?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I want to add a point on my map by typing in the coordinates. It's working fine, but I can't covert my input to actual map coordinates. It's taking the value of the screen and converting that to the coordinate.

For example, if I type in (0,0) it puts the point on the (0,0) screen position, which is the coordinate (78.46671909721232, -74.02100401110448). I check this with the console.log output. How do I ask it to put a point on (0,0) longitude/latitude?

I've added the code below for reference.

```
TextField {
           id: xcoordtext
           anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
           validator: DoubleValidator {bottom: -90.00; top: 90.00;}
           Layout.fillWidth:   true
        }
TextField {
           id: ycoordtext
           anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
           validator: DoubleValidator {bottom: -90.00; top: 90.00;}
           Layout.fillWidth:   true
        }
Button {
         text:               "POINT Confirmed"
         Layout.fillWidth:   true

         onClicked: {
              var waypointCoord = myMap.toCoordinate(Qt.point(xcoordtext.text,ycoordtext.text), false)
              console.log(waypointCoord.longitude, waypointCoord.latitude)
           }
        }
```

The error and message that is coming in the console log is as follows:-

```
"Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is dangerous and deprecated."
"This will throw a JavaScript TypeError in future releases of Qt!"
qml: -106.9871520804946 79.58494957851264
Ignored NaN, Inf, or -Inf value.
Attempting to set invalid range for value axis: [ nan  -  nan ]
TerrainQueryLog: Error in fetching elevation tile. Empty response.
Ignored NaN, Inf, or -Inf value.
Attempting to set invalid range for value axis: [ nan  -  nan ]
```

Where `qml: -106.9871520804946 79.58494957851264` are the coordinates I get when I type in 0 (`xcoordtext.text`) and 0(`ycoord.text`) in the TextField inputs.

Comment: how do you "put" the point? please provide [mre]. Did you try use [coordinate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapquickitem.html#coordinate-prop) property too update the item position?

Comment: By "put" I really meant add. Essentially I just wanted to know how I could convert my TextEdit integer input to map coordinates. I've tried it with Qt.point(), and then toCoordinate, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `toCoordinate` does the work. But since you didn't provide [mre] it's hard to guess what a problem. Did you try to print `waypointCoord`? I doubt that you do that wrong, `Qt.point` requires `int`, not string.

Comment: I have printed `waypointCoord` using `console.log()` as shown in the question. I've edited the question and added the exact error message as well. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I write this Example for you , as I understand from your question.
if you want that user adds lat and long in TextInput and then add a point on this coordinate you shouldn't convert anything.

I use TextInput instead of TextField to getting user input.

in this example, user add x and y number from -90 to 90 and in map add that point by red circle.

in the bottom right of the screen I put a white rect that shows mouse position in lat and long in this , I convert screen x and y to lat and long .

as you can see the differences, and also you can see that mouse that points to the red circle show exactly the point that the user adds from text input .

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.9
import QtPositioning 5.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {

Plugin
{
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "osm"
}
Map
{
    id: map
    anchors.rightMargin: 0
    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
    anchors.leftMargin: 0
    anchors.topMargin: 0
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(29.7264175,55.99735)
    zoomLevel: 5
    copyrightsVisible: false
    focus: true

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: map
        hoverEnabled: true
        onPositionChanged:  {

            lat.text ="Lat :"+ map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)).latitude.toString()
            lon.text ="Lon :"+ map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouseX,mouseY)).longitude.toString()

        }

    }

    property Component itemDelegate: Component{
        Rectangle {
            width: 14
            height: 14
            radius: 7
            color: "red"
        }
    }



    MapItemView{
        id: item_view
        model: ListModel{
            id: item_model
        }
        delegate: MapQuickItem{
            id: ietm_delegate
            zoomLevel: 0
            sourceItem: Loader{
                sourceComponent: map.itemDelegate
            }
            coordinate{
                latitude: latitudeval
                longitude: longitudeval
            }
            anchorPoint: Qt.point(sourceItem.width/2, sourceItem.height/2)
        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        width: 251
        height: 163
        color: "#ffffff"
        border.color: "#000000"
        border.width: 1

        TextInput {
            id: textInput_x
            x: 68
            y: 25
            width: 175
            height: 30
            font.pixelSize: 16
            validator: DoubleValidator {bottom: -90.00; top: 90.00;}
            focus: true

        }

        TextInput {
            id: textInput_y
            x: 68
            y: 60
            width: 175
            height: 24
            font.pixelSize: 16
            focus: true

            validator: DoubleValidator {bottom: -90.00; top: 90.00;}
        }

        Label {
            id: label
            x: 20
            y: 25
            width: 53
            height: 30
            text: qsTr("x :")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        Label {
            id: label1
            x: 20
            y: 60
            width: 53
            height: 30
            text: qsTr("Y :")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        Button {
            x: 8
            y: 113
            text:               "POINT Confirmed"
            Layout.fillWidth:   true

            onClicked: {
                var waypointCoord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(textInput_x.text,textInput_y.text))

                item_model.append({"latitudeval":textInput_y.text,"longitudeval":textInput_x.text});

                console.log(waypointCoord.longitude, waypointCoord.latitude)
            }
        }
    }






    Rectangle {
        width: 206
        height: 50
        color: "white"
        anchors.top: parent.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: -50
        anchors.left: parent.right
        anchors.leftMargin: -206

        Text {
            id: lat
            width: 206
            height: 24

        }

        Text {
            id: lon
            x: 0
            y: 24
            width: 206
            height: 26

        }


    }

}
}
```

[image: out put image]